QuestDB Azure UNSUPPORTED (SYSTEM COULD BE UNSTABLE), how to fix?
I need to choose a disk to run QuestDB on Azure. I tried using Blob Fuse2 file system over Azure Blob Storage but the database crashed a few times and I suspect it's because of file system. I'm using v7.4.0 and see this on the start log:
UNSUPPORTED (SYSTEM COULD BE UNSTABLE)db root: 
[path=/var/lib/questdb/db, magic=0x65735546] -> UNSUPPORTED (SYSTEM COULD BE UNSTABLE)

How can I run QuestDB in Azure?
